New to playwright, can't get any headful browsers to launch
I'm attempting to do an intro to playwright tutorial and can't get any headful browser to open. I'm working on a Windows 11 computer in jupyter notebook (a requirement for the program I'm in) and all I'm trying to do is run the pre-written code from the tutorial, as follows:
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, expect
playwright = await async_playwright().start()
browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)

When I run the code and try to launch a chromium browser, nothing happens. When I try to launch a firefox browser, the Nightly icon appears in my toolbar and I get a popup asking if I want to open Nightly in troubleshoot mode. But when I click open, the Nightly icon disappears and nothing happens.
Any advice or pointers are much appreciated!

Maybe it’s too fast for you to notice it?

await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=False)

Opens an empty browser, if you didn't state any further actions such as goto() it will open and browser and close it immediately.
Try running a single test() that navigates to a URL, and include await page.pause() to verify if the browser displays the URL you navigated to.
